# Invoke async operation with result

Tags: go

Can you provide a pattern of how to invoke method async with result?
is there any best practice to invoke it by configuration sync/async

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you have to search for is `goroutines`

Here is one example: https://gobyexample.com/goroutines

If you follow the tutorial, channels, buffered channels and syncronized channels will give you some way to return data.

Example 2: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1

Example 3: http://www.golangbootcamp.com/book/concurrency

TL;DR: Here is your pattern:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func sum(a []int, c chan int) {
    sum := 0
    for _, v := range a {
        sum += v
    }
    c <- sum // send sum to c
}

func main() {
    a := []int{7, 2, 8, -9, 4, 0}

    c := make(chan int)
    go sum(a[:len(a)/2], c)
    go sum(a[len(a)/2:], c)
    x, y := <-c, <-c // receive from c

    fmt.Println(x, y, x+y)
}
```